# Remainder when $26^{3008} + 3008^{26}$ is divided by $4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

I want to find the  Remainder when $26^{3008} + 3008^{26}$ is divided by $4$.
What should I do?
Even though I've included the tag modular arithmetic I've very limited knowledge about it.
How should I approach this problem?

Comment: An even number, raised to a power $> 1$, is it divisible by $4$?

Comment: @DanielFischer lol how could I not realize that ,  Thank you !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

$3008$ is divisible by $4$

$26^2$ is divisible by $4$

Comment: 3008 is divisible by 4. I am not sure about it.

Comment: $3008=4*752$ hence $3008$ is divisible by $4$.

Comment: @Sreenidhi You can use the divisibility test for 4 which states if last two digits of a number are divisible by 4 then the number is divisible by 4 .In this case the last two digits are 08 which is clearly divisible by 4.

Answer (score 0):

26 = 2 mod 4

26^2 = 0 mod 4

(26^2)^1504 = 0^1504 mod 4

26^3008 = 0 mod 4 ..................1

3008 = 0 mod 4.

therefore 3008^26 = 0^26 mod 4 ........2

adding 1 and 2

26^3008 + 3008^26 = 0 mod 4

Therefore remainder is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Both 26 and 3008 contain factors of 2, so if they are raised to any power they will be divisible by 4. Thus, the remainder is 0.